How to handle cors in express js? It works with the HTTP module but the origin in the header undefined in express js
I’m using the Express.js framework and trying to handle CORS, but req.headers.origin is returning undefined. I have a whitelist of allowed origins in my corsOptions, and I'm checking the origin in the headers. Why is the origin header coming back as undefined, and how can I fix it?
Here, what I'm trying.
const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
        origin: function (origin, callback) {
                // origin is undefined
                if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
                        callback(null, true)
                } else {
                        callback("Not allowed by CORS")
                }
        },

        credentials: true, //access-control-allow-credentials:true
        optionSuccessStatus: 200,
        exposedHeaders: ['Content-Disposition']

}

process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" && app.use(helmet());

/**
 * Middleware
 */

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
        extended: true
}));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.disable('x-powered-by');

// Api
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
        // req.headers.origin is undefined
        // req.header.get("origin") is undefined
        res.send("Response success");
});



Not every request has an Origin header. It is omitted, for example, in same-origin GET requests. What is the request in your case?

I have a POST and GET APIs. Like signup and login.

Are they same-origin? I'd expect an Origin header in the POST, but not the GET request, then.

Yes, they are the same-origin. Origin is undefined either it is POST or GET

Your code is correct, in the absence of Origin, the request is allowed. Maybe not all browsers include this header in same-origin POST requests.

Using node built-in HTTP module. This code block worked in every browser. I think the problem may be from the express side. Anyways, thank you

The Origin header is set only if you make the request from a browser, not when you make it from the Node.js http module.

I'm actually talking about the creation of APIs using a built-in Node Module HTTP and not using a framework like Express Js.

Update:
You do not need CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) for requests made to the same origin. They are allowed by default. So you can remove the middleware completely in case you need to allow only the same origin. All request from other origins will be blocked anyway.
===
Ensure that the requests you’re testing include the Origin header: For instance, if you’re testing with a simple GET request from the same origin, the Origin header might not be included.
If you do not want to block REST tools or server-to-server requests, add a !origin check in the origin function like so:
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}


Right now, I'm using exactly the same check !origin. But, I want to allow only the same origin to request GET, POST, etc.

I just updated the post in case you wanted to use only the same origin.

I got it. That means the origin header is present when the request comes from other than the same origin. Right?

Using of cors in general is for other origins. Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows a web page to access restricted resources from a server on a domain different than the domain that served the web page. In GET requests from the same origin, the Origin header might not be included.

Now I clearly understand. That is what I was confused about. Thanks @Grisho4ek

Mark my answer as correct in that case :)
